# How do I redirect with ajax to a dynamic link in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, routes

I'm trying to return a view with some data in it with ajax

I tried like this:

```
            $.ajax({
            url: '/canvas',
            data:{
                size:data.drawing['canvas_size'],
                name: data.drawing['name'],
                id: data.drawing['id']
            }
           });`
```

and this is the route:

```
Route::get('canvas/{size}/{name?}/{id?}',[DrawingController::class,'canvas'])->name('canvas');
```

it just gives the 404 error,can you help me please?

Comment: `{data : ...}` will generate Query String parameters, like `/canvas?size=...&name=...&id=...`. If you want to use Route Parameters, you need to specify them in the URL, like `url: '/canvas' + data.drawing['canvas_size'] + '/' + data.drawing['name'] + '/' + data.drawing['id']`. I would suggest avoiding that though, as Route Parameters can be problematic when you have a lot of them, and if you have multiple optional ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either send the data in the uri using the route

```
Route::get('canvas/{size}/{name?}/{id?}',[DrawingController::class,'canvas'])->name('canvas');
```

like this

```
.ajax({
    url: '/canvas/'+ data.drawing['canvas_size'] + '/' + data.drawing['name'] + '/' +  data.drawing['id'],
});`
```

Or send the data in the body / url query string using the route

```
Route::get('canvas',[DrawingController::class,'canvas'])->name('canvas');
```

using

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/canvas',
    data:{
        size:data.drawing['canvas_size'],
        name: data.drawing['name'],
        id: data.drawing['id']
    }
});
```

and get the variable inside your controller with

DrawingController

```
public function canvas($request)
{
    $size = $request->size;
    $name = $request->name;
    $id = $request->id;

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note: This answer will only work in a `blade.php` file.**

Route parameters are used for readable urls. Do this your request with request GET parameters. So update your route:

```
Route::get('canvas',[DrawingController::class,'canvas'])->name('canvas');
```

And use:

```
url: "{{ route('canvas') }}"
```

You can also follow a directive like this if you want to use it with route parameters. But putting variables from javascript here can mess things up:

```
url: "{{ route('canvas', [$var1, $var2, $var3]) }}",
```

Comment: `{{ }}` is `.blade.php` syntax, and `route()` is a PHP function; neither of those will work in JS, unless that `$.ajax()` is within a `<script>` tag of a `.blade.php` file, which there is no indication of in this question. So while this answer _might_ work, it's making a lot of assumptions. (Sorry, only meant to comment, not downvote too; mis-clicked there)